# Running two apps on a single server name with different ports on NGINX

Tags: nginx

Good day SO.

I don't know if I used the right terminology on my question but I will try to explain what my concern is and what I am trying to achieve.

I have an app that runs on the NGINX server with SSL (port 443). on this app, my domainName/chatroom page is saved. i can open this no problem but there is no connection. To connect the chat room, there is another (app?) that is on a different root folder and can be run by NPM server with port 3000. With these setup, the app works, Connection and all. My question is how can I make the app, instead of running on NPM server every time to run on NGINX server instead.

here is my NGINX config file:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
ssl_certificate     /path/to/cert/mydomain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key/mydomain-key.pem;

server_name mydomain;
root /path/to/project/mydomain;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
    try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name mydomain;

return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

root folders:

```
/path/to/project/mydomain
/path/to/project/mydomain-chat
```

I tried to create a new server block with the same server_name with port 3000 but did not work.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly. You need to create a new NGINX configuration file, see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-run-node-js-server-with-nginx

Comment: I tried to add the proxy_pass on my config but it returns `control process exited with error code` when restarting my nginx server. I added it under server block that listens on port 443. 

this was proxy pass that I added:

`location /  {
 proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3010/;
 try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}`

Comment: typo.. i changed 3010 to 3000, still the same error message.

Comment: Don't put the `proxy_pass` and `try_files` in the same `location` - you are either handing off the request to another server, or looking for files in this server, not both.

Comment: When you talk about the "*NPM server*" on port 3000, it sounds like you have a separate Node.js app.  So when you ask "*how can I make the app, instead of running on NPM server every time to run on NGINX server instead*", do you mean how do you keep the Node.js app running (because it keeps stopping)? or do you mean you want to serve the same as that app serves but from within nginx?

Comment: want to serve the same as that app serves but from within nginx.